# Echo output of a piped command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, echo

I am trying to just echo a command within my bash script code.

```
OVERRUN_ERRORS="$ifconfig | egrep -i "RX errors" | awk '{print $7}'"
echo ${OVERRUN_ERRORS}
```

however it gives me an error and the $7 does not show up in the command. I have to store it in a variable, because I will process the output (OVERRUN_ERRORS) at a later point in time. What's the right syntax for doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Why it is `$ifconfig`?

Comment: The assignment to `OVERRUN_ERRORS` does not execute any command as written (`OVERRUN_ERRORS="$ifconfig | egrep -i "RX errors" | awk '{print $7}'"`).  What are you really doing?  What does `bash -x the-script.sh` show?

Comment: BTW -- is there a reason you're extracting this from `ifconfig`, rather than lifting it directly from sysfs (which is where ifconfig itself gets it from)? Pulling it straight from the source is going to be more reliable in terms of not needing to worry about future changes in ifconfig's output format messing up your script.

Comment: There's also no reason to use both `grep` and `awk`. `awk '/RX errors/ { print $7 }'` does the work of both in one command.

Answer (score 7):

#### On Bash Syntax

```
foo="bar | baz"
```

...is assigning the **string** "bar | baz" to the variable named `foo`; it doesn't run `bar | baz` as a pipeline. To do that, you want to use [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), in either its modern `$()` syntax or antiquated backtick-based form:

```
foo="$(bar | baz)"
```

---

#### On Storing Code For Later Execution

Since your intent isn't clear in the question --

The correct way to store *code* is with a function, whereas the correct way to store *output* is in a string:

```
# store code in a function; this also works with pipelines
get_rx_errors() { cat /sys/class/net/"$1"/statistics/rx_errors; }

# store result of calling that function in a string
eth0_errors="$(get_rx_errors eth0)"

sleep 1 # wait a second for demonstration purposes, then...

# compare: echoing the stored value, vs calculating a new value
echo "One second ago, the number of rx errors was ${eth0_errors}"
etho "Right now, it is $(get_rx_errors eth0)"
```

See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for an extended discussion of the pitfalls of storing code in a string, and alternatives to same. Also relevant is [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), which describes in detail the security risks associated with a `eval`, which is often suggested as a workaround.

---

#### On Collecting Interface Error Counts

Don't use `ifconfig`, or `grep`, or `awk` for this at all -- just ask your kernel for the number you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
for device in /sys/class/net/*; do
  [[ -e $device/statistics/rx_errors ]] || continue
  rx_errors=$(<"${device}/statistics/rx_errors")
  echo "Number of rx_errors for ${device##*/} is $rx_errors"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$(...)` to capture the output of a command, not double quotes.

```
overrun_errors=$(ifconfig | egrep -i "RX errors" | awk '{print $7}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes around `RX errors` are a problem.  Try;

```
OVERRUN_ERRORS="$ifconfig | egrep -i 'RX errors' | awk '{print $7}'"
```

To see the commands as they are executing, you can use

```
set -v
```

or

```
set -x
```

For example;

```
set -x 
OVERRUN_ERRORS="$ifconfig | egrep -i 'RX errors' | awk '{print $7}'"
set +x
```

Comment: The OP says clearly in the question that they want **output** of the command -- that is, that they want the command to actually be run. Making the change you suggest here does not cause that to happen.

Comment: If they were going to `eval "$OVERRUN_ERRORS"` rather than `echo "$OVERRUN_ERRORS"`, we might be having a different discussion (but it'd also be one about how storing code in strings is a bad practice in general, with lots of references to [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the OP wrote 'I am trying to just echo a command', and he is trying to use `echo`.  He says 'the $7 does not show up in the command', not 'does not show up in the output'.  I don't think my interpretation of that text is unreasonable at all.  If he said 'I am trying to run a command', or some such, I would have talked about eval.

Comment: Look at the title. "echo output of a piped command" -- those exact words, in that exact order.